# How to configure this email action globally in Oozie?

Tags: apache-spark, email, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I have around 50 workflows like this, below code just an example,

```
<workflow-app name="exit_1_email_test" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="ssh-8e73"/>
    <action name="Kill">
        <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.2">
            <to>***</to>
            <cc>***</cc>
            <subject>exit1_email_test workflow failed</subject>
            <body>exit1_email_test workflow failed on</body>
        </email>
        <ok to="Kill-kill"/>
        <error to="Kill-kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="Kill-kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="ssh-8e73">
        <ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
            <host>ubuntu@ip-address.ec2.internal</host>
            <command>bash /home/ubuntu/exit_1.sh</command>
            <capture-output/>
        </ssh>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

I am configuring email action for the workflows so that I can receive notifications in case of any failures.

The parameters in the email action will be mostly same except the workflow name.

How can I configure this email action globally in Oozie instead of configuring the same in each workflow?

Answer (score 1):

One of the option is to place the configured email action in a separate workflow and execute it as an sub-workflow in each of 50 workflows:

[Sub-workflow Action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.1/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.6_Sub-workflow_Action)

```
...
    <action name="send-email">
        <sub-workflow>
            <app-path>[PATH-TO-EMAIL-WORKFLOW-FILE]</app-path>
            <propagate-configuration/>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>[WF-NAME-OR-OTHER-PROPERTY-NAME]</name>
                    <value>[PROPERTY-VALUE]</value>
                </property>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </sub-workflow>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
 ...
```